# Насупиться — от слова «суп»?

Tags: этимология, словообразование, однокоренные-слова

Насупиться — помрачнеть. Интересно, это слово имеет что-то общее со словом "суп" или просто созвучно?

Answer (score 1):

У Шанского: насупиться (супиться) образовано от слова "суп", что является вариантом названия "коршун". Сравнить: ершиться, петушиться, ёржиться.

ИНФОРМАЦИЯ ИЗ ИНТЕРНЕТА

В древнерусском языке было слово суп, означавшее хищную птицу - коршуна или грифа. Данные современного русского языка позволяют сделать вывод о том, что этой птице приписывали:

(А) исключительное корыстолюбие; 
(Б) очень высокую скорость полёта; 
(В) мрачный взгляд; 
(Г) жертвенную любовь к птенцам; 
(Д) способность воскресать после смерти.

Answer (score 1):

По Фасмеру:
**насу́питься** — укр. насу́пити чо́ло, блр. супiць "хмурить", цслав. осѫпѣти "оробеть", чеш. posupiti "омрачить", польск. sępić — то же; см. Мi. ЕW 315. Обычно сближают с цслав. сѫпъ γύψ, сербохорв. су̑п, чеш., слвц. suр "коршун, гриф", польск. sęр — то же. Др. ступень чередования *sępъ представлена в сербохорв. се̏п — то же; см. Булаховский, ОЛЯ 7, 119.

В старославянском было суп (через юс), остаток от него "соп, суп" в совр. диалектах — вид коршуна. У Есенина: *Вечер чёрные брови насопил.*
Суп ("гриф", "коршун") — супиться + на = насупиться — уподобиться коршуну (кстати, очень похоже на нахохлившегося коршуна). Так же, как осоветь — уподобиться сове.

http://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-8289.htm

Comment: А суп (похлёбка)-французское заимствование.