# Этимология слова "суп"

Tags: этимология

Вопрос простой: происхождение слова "суп" и может ли оно являться родственником глаголу "насупиться"?

Answer (score 1):

Этот вопрос обсуждался, и источники с этимологией для обоих слов цитировались здесь:

["Насупиться" - от слова "суп"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/29949/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF)

У Фасмера это отдельные словарные статьи (корни разного происхождения), хотя в сети их иногда объединяют из желания сопоставить "похожести". Слово "суп" заимствовано из французского, но возникло в старо-немецком, напр. в английский (как soup) оно попало оттуда. Изначально это слово означало блюдо в виде отвара. Однако в слове "насупиться" все источники ссылаются на славянский (сразу в нескольких языках этой группы, с вариациями в написании и звучании) корень, связанный с хищной птицей. Смысл выводится такой, что нахмуриваясь, человек становится мрачным и уподобляется такой птице. Не видно причин считать эти два слова родственными.

Comment: "Не видно причин" — дети часто не хотят есть суп и от этого насупиваются.

Comment: Зато супруга Юсупова супрематически не насупливалась перед супостатами.

Comment: А может, и насупливалась, когда ела невкусный суп.

Comment: Невкусный суп проще скормить Юсупову - чтобы не псуподхвост.

Comment: "Псу под хвост" - отдельно. Юсупов супы не ест, он сильно юсупится от этого.

Comment: Александр, спасибо вам за ответ! Но имеется просьба: балаган не разводит, пожалуйста.!